# There is no implicit reference conversion

Tags: c#

I have the following code which doesn't compile. I can't figure out why. Can someone please help?

```
var mercedes = new Mercedes().WithEngine(new LargeEngine());
var volkswagen = new Volkswagen().WithEngine(new SmallEngine());

public class Mercedes : Car<LargeEngine>
{
}

public class Volkswagen: Car<SmallEngine>
{
}

public class Engine
{
}

public class LargeEngine : Engine
{
}

public class SmallEngine : Engine
{
}

public class Car<T> where T : Engine
{
    internal T? Engine { get; set; }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static TCar WithEngine<TCar>(this TCar car, Engine engine)
        where TCar : Car<Engine>
    {
        car.Engine = engine;

        return car;
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't compile with the  error:

> The type 'Mercedes' cannot be used as type parameter 'TCar' in the
> generic type or method 'ExtensionMethods.WithConfiguration(TCar,
> Engine)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Mercedes' to
> 'Car<Engine>'

What I understand is that 'Mercedes' type cannot be casted implicitly into 'Car<Engine>' type. But I also cannot figure out a way to cast it explicitly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify the definition of the WithEngine extension method to take a generic type parameter that is constrained to the Car class, where T is a type parameter that is derived from the Engine class.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static TCar WithEngine<TCar, TEngine>(this TCar car, TEngine engine)
        where TCar : Car<TEngine>
        where TEngine : Engine
    {
        car.Engine = engine;

        return car;
    }
}
```

### Why?

`Car<LargeEngine>` does not inherit from `Car<Engine>`, and cannot be implicitly converted to it.

Imagine if generic types *did* implement inheritance like this. Then we would be able to write the following code:

```cs
Mercedes mercedes = new Mercedes();
Car<Engine> car = mercedes;

// Clearly *this* should not be allowed
car.Engine = new SmallEngine();
```

Comment: I was going to say that too. I validate this answer.